# reset a timer in GLFW

Tags: c++, timer, glfw

I have this piece of code:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        double currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        //some code
}
```

so `currentFrame` will increment every time, so I want to reset it to 0 if it exceeds 5 ms (it's in ms naturally?)

how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, [`glfwGetTime()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gaa6cf4e7a77158a3b8fd00328b1720a4a) works with seconds. It returns the time that has passed since the application started (or more precisely, since GLFW library was initialized).

The way you can do what you want is by setting a new time with [`glfwSetTime()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gaf59589ef6e8b8c8b5ad184b25afd4dc0). The glfwGetTime() will return you the time from the point you have specified. But I suggest you don't do that, just subtract the last frame time from the current time and you will get a time that has passed since last frame.